# Un-downvote an answer that probably won't be edited

Tags: support, answers, downvotes, specific-answer

I saw [an answer that doesn't really answer the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680778/how-do-you-open-a-file-from-within-vim/54873421#54873421) and I think it won't be edited. What should I do to un-downvote it? Do a useless edit? Nobody will approve it.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: _Why_ do you want to remove your downvote?

Comment: I dont want to loose my repo on such answers. I didnt't know that I will loose it for my downvote.

Comment: If the answer gets deleted you get your rep back but your vote is important to signal to visitors and reviewers that the answer isn't useful.

Comment: You are doing the community a service with your vote. Do not undo it. It’s likely that answer will end up deleted and you’ll get your rep back.

Comment: It will be deleted automatically according to some rule?

Comment: Not automatically. But it is very bad and will be flagged. Its odds are slim. Now that meta knows about it, very, very slim.

Comment: Very very slim that it will survive, I believe is what @yivi means.  These types of answers are common, and likely the most prolific usage of the Not An Answer flag.  Feel free to downvote, flag as NaA, and move on.  Won't take long to get your rep back.

Comment: Yes, I meant what @fbueckert said. Thought it was clear enough.

Comment: The answer has been deleted and your rep should be back.

Answer (score 11):

You did the right thing by downvoting this answer. When you downvote an answer that is completely incorrect, you are helping the community.

Also these type of answers are usually deleted by trusted users.

[Why are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

> Answers can also be deleted by the community. Moderators can delete any answer, and trusted community members can vote to delete answers scoring -1 or lower (3 votes will result in deletion).

So when you downvoted, you helped those trusted members to vote to delete the answer, therefore there is nothing to worry about in this case.